# Activation of network connection failed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: internet

I'm not able to connect to internet through wifi or ethernet it just keep showing network activation faild.I would appreciate simple answers, for I am still very new Linux, thank you.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your clock is set to the correct time/year. Sometimes network protocols "synchronize" based on system time and will refuse to authorize if the times are drastically out of sync:

Answer is from [No Wifi - “Activation of network connection failed” Ubuntu 16.04 & 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058719/no-wifi-activation-of-network-connection-failed-ubuntu-16-04-18-04)